# Responsive Layout - Content Breaks

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a page layout with the following html structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col3">test 1</div>
    <div class="col3">test 2</div>
    <div class="col3">test 3</div>
</div>
```

Using the following css, I wanted to make a simple, responsive layout:

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 1.25%;
    padding-right: 1.25%;
    margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
}
.col3 {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1.25%;
    border: none;
}
```

Why is it when I shrink my page to 30% of the width of my screen, the last column drops down underneath the other rows?

Is there something im not accounting for? I would have thought it would have just continued to get narrower and narrower. What causes it to create a content break, and drop down a row.

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's from `display: inline-block`. If you float your columns to the left they will work as expected.

When you use `display: inline-block` spaces/returns etc between the elements that have `inline-block` applied to them will be taken into account and rendered. You can think of it as adding a single space between each inline-block element.

This is the main downside of using `display: inline-block` over floats in my humble opinion.

```css
.col3 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 1.25%;
    border: none;
}
```

You could also remedy this by doing the following if you wanted to continue using `display: inline-block` but they're hackerish. ***I would advise against either of these solutions.***

**no space between elements**

```
<div class="col3">test 1</div><div class="col3">test 1</div><div class="col3">test 1</div>
```

**comments between elements**

```
<div class="col3">test 1</div><!--
--><div class="col3">test 1</div><!-- 
--><div class="col3">test 1</div>
```

Comment: I had know clue that this happens. Very interesting. Thanks for your answer.  In your opinion @hungerstar, is it more'hackish' to clear floats or simply comment out the spaces?

Comment: Not sure I follow as commenting out spaces would not clear floats.

Comment: I mean, if I use floats, I would have to then clear floats, to get the .row to take the height of it's inner columns. If i user display: inline-block, .row gets it's height from the inner columns by default.

Comment: I would use a clearfix so the floated elements are accounted for, http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/.

Comment: Thats awesome, realized how my answer wasn't a good solution at all. Thumbs up.

Comment: @Chique your answer would be more appropriate for someone who finds themselves running into a pixel rendering issue.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem lies with the lines

```
.col3 {
    ..
    width:30%;
    margin: 0 1.25%;
    ..
}
```

As width is 30% of the row, but while you are narrowing it down, the margin is actually getting wider with respect to the row, its a common thing which happens to inline-block display type.

If you drop the margin line, or simply change the width of the margin to

```
margin: 0 1%;
```

it would be fixed.

No need to worry about fixing inline-blocks, or having to deal with its downsides.

Comment: For me this is *not* a "proper" fix. This leaves a 4% gap on the right side, `1% + 30% + 1% * 3 = 96%`;